# Why are my 3D plots getting inverted?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, inverse

For some reason, all 3D plots that I make in Mathematica 9 get inverted in both the image and the axes. For example, using the simple plot:

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Gives the following image:

[image]

When I use the mouse to rotate the image, it snaps back to the normal orientation and I can rotate freely. When I release the image, it inverts itself again. The above images was saved as a png, if I save it as a pdf, the orientation is normal.

The same inversion happens for a DensityPlot, but not for a regular Plot.

What is happening here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: This happened suddenly, I mean, Mathematica behaved normally earlier? Have you recently updated anything? Or perhaps you should update your graphics drivers?

Comment: The mathematica I used is hosted on the university server. Before this I used the mathematica 10 trial version locally, which worked fine. So I guess it could be the graphics drivers of the server that are outdated?

Comment: This is just awesome!

Comment: @halirutan you like inverted graphics?

Comment: Have you checked your monitor isn't rotated thru 180 degrees?

Comment: You win again, anti-gravity!

Comment: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464